# Ember - How to insert record only when save() is complete

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an application that can support multiple languages. Each of my users have their own set of "supported language". Let's say my user support english, french and spanish, he can create a category for his shop and he will have to input the name in 3 language. However, when I show the list of the categories, I only want to show in my  tag the selected language name.

I made the following function in my controller and it work perfectly :

```
App.CategoryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({   
    needs: ['settings'],
    currentLocale: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.settings.currentLocale'),
    name: function() {
        var translations = this.get('category_translation_ids').filterBy('locale', this.get('currentLocale'));
        Ember.assert("The selected language does not exist", translations.length === 1);
        return translations[0].get('name');
    }.property('category_translation_ids.@each.name') 
});
```

My problem is when I add a new category :

```
App.CategoriesAddController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({   
    needs: ['categories', 'settings'],
    newRecord: function() {
        scope = this;
        record = this.store.createRecord( 'category', 
                                          {
                                               active: true,
                                          })
        record.save().then(function(record) {
            scope.get('controllers.settings').get('supportedLocale').forEach(function(item, index, enumerable) {
                translation = scope.get('store').createRecord( 'categoryTranslation', 
                                                {
                                                    locale: item,
                                                    name: 'Nom',
                                                    description: '',
                                                    meta_description: ''
                                                });
                record.get('category_translation_ids').pushObject(translation);
                translation.save();
            });
        });
    },
});
```

As soon as I do "createRecord" my Category is created and the computed property "name" can't execute because I haven't yet inserted the translation. I have no idea if I'm doing it the right way as this is my first project in ember. I'm on this problem since that last 4-5 hours without much success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that I completely understand your problem, but something that might help to know is that `save()` actually returns a promise. So if you needed to execute something after the save has finished, just call `save().then(function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you've got a template showing all of the categories, and the item controller for the category is `CategoryController`.  Probably something like this:

```
{{#each category in controller}} 
  {{category.name}}
{{/each}}
```

As I'm sure is happening to you, when the controller attempts to calculate `name` on the controller it crashes.  There are a few ways you can accomplish this, one being filtering if the category isn't new.

```
{{#each category in controller}} 
  {{#unless category.isNew}}
    {{category.name}}
  {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

You can also filter based on the state of the record, though that changes frequently and there are a plethora of different states.

Comment: Actually it might be better to use "newRecord" rather than rely on id. I've had issues in the past where sometimes id is present even though the record hasn't been saved yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm aware of any built in property/state called `newRecord`, but I haven't been in Ember Data much in the last month, feel free to enlighten.  `id` is a way you can generally handle it, I guess if you are creating ids client side, which is quite uncommon, this wouldn't work.  You can also set a property on the object then remove it once the record's been saved, excluding records with that property from the loop.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I meant "isNew" :) Sometimes I get a bit confused between frameworks and languages I'm currently using ;-)